# How to view my custom game engines' features?

Tags: game-dev-tycoon

I created several custom game engines but I forgot their features. Is there a way to look their features or not?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any direct way. Though if you want to find out after the fact, I propose to develop a small game, all parts you added to your old engine will be available for you to select as feature. Of course for that you have to actively create a game, but you can write the available features down at this time and have the knowledge available for next time.

In addition:

- Always put meaningful names there to identify different Engines.
- Also: If you select: Create new Custom Engine, You see the items you selected previously (of course this only works for Engine you created last time).

Comment: explanation why -1? So I can modify where needed?

Comment: I didn't downvote but I have to admit you're not answering the question. I'd suggest making it clear you don't think there's a clear way to see previous engines' features *except* in cases 2 and 3 you give. I still find point 1 unhelpful in the context though.

Comment: I personally find point 1 the best. Because I can create a game (small game would suffice) and write down what is in any engine (no matter how old). Then I would know next time. 3 is only of limited use because you can find out only for last engine.

Comment: If you look at the question: *I forgot their features* and *Is there a way to look their features or not?* implies looking for them *after* creating the game, in a case where you did *not* note them down. Thus, saying "you should note them down first" is not a direct answer. Sometimes indirect answers are OK, sometimes they're not. Just saying it may be the reason for the downvote.

Comment: +1 for correct answer.  If you want to know what's in the engine, you either wrote it down or you make a new game with it.